# AWS, proxy on one.com CORS issues

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, tomcat, proxy

I have a tomcat web service hosted on AWS (ESB to be more precise). When I host a website locally calling this web service everything works fine.

I have bought a domain on one.com which simply redirects to this domain because I want to be able to change hosting address without redeploying my website and or apps.

When I enter my proxy address in the browser it calls the web service fine and I get data. However, when I call the proxy from my web application hosted locally I experience CORS issues No Access-control-allow-origin headers. Could it be that one.com simply redirects my request and not sends headers back and forth? In this case how can I handle this?

If you need any info just ask, I am not sure where to look.

Comment: does your server send CORS headers?

Comment: Yes, I have a response filter that includes this in all requests. Otherwise I also do not think it would work even without the proxy.

Comment: Redirecting won't add cors headers

Comment: Then What Can I do?

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by "application hosted locally"

Comment: Yes, well, in the end it will not be hosted locally but it should be the same. It is an angular application which is distributed and hosted on a tomcat locally on my pc. At some point it will be hosted on some domain probably via. one.com (though not the proxy domain).